# Как массово удалить определенный текст из mysql?

Tags: mysql

Есть большая база (10к записей), там в тексте у всех записей есть битые фотографии, которые нужно удалить.
Встречаются вот такие:

```
<p dir="ltr"><img src="https://site.ru/images/5795.jpg" class="fr-fic fr-dii"></p>

<p dir="ltr"><img src="https://site.ru/images/1241.jpg" class="fr-fic fr-dii"></p>
```

То есть фото разные, нужно как то удалить все строки где есть тег p и внутри фото. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace)

Comment: А как именно сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE base_name SET text = REGEXP_REPLACE(full_text, '<p dir="ltr"><img src="https://site.ru/images/.*?[^"]" class="fr-fic fr-dii"></p>', '')
```